# Comparing BOOL values Objective_C

Tags: objective-c

I saved BOOL value for two keys in NSUserDefaults, while reading the value the results are not as expected.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults synchronize];

NSLog(@"A_Key:%u B_Key:%u", [userDefaults boolForKey:A_KEY], [userDefaults boolForKey:B_KEY]);
```

//Logs: A_Key:1 B_Key:0

```
if([userDefaults    boolForKey:A_KEY]){
    _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex=0;
}else{
    if([userDefaults    boolForKey:B_KEY]){
        _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex=1;
    }}
```

Can't find what I am missing / doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: When you say results are not as expected, What do you actually expect?
I see the output 0 and 1.

Comment: Surely you only need to store one boolean value in the user defaults - if it is NO then _segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0, if it is YES then _segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1?

Comment: @thatzprem, I mean none of the if statements are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect to happen? BOOLs are [represented as numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/FoundationTypesandCollections/FoundationTypesandCollections.html) (1 = true, 0 = false):

> The NSNumber class is used to represent any of the basic C scalar
>   types, including char, double, float, int, long, short, and the
>   unsigned variants of each, as well as the Objective-C Boolean type,
>   BOOL.

Your if-statement should work in any case, doesn't it?

Comment: According to your log output, `_segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex=0;` should be called.

Comment: yes, that's what i said "expected". but its not called.

Comment: Yes, both if statements are evaluated false.

Comment: This is (nearly) impossible. Is there additional code that you didn't paste?